# Apply a function on a single element of a tuple

Tags: python, list, function, tuples, apply

With a direct example it would be easier to understand

```
data = [(1995, 50.28), (1996, 28.52)]
```

```
result = [(1995, 50), (1996, 29)]
```

I would like to apply a transformation only on the second number of each tuple (50.28 and 28.52).

I saw the map() function that could help, but i think it works only on ALL elements, and having tuples inside list makes it a bit tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more intuitive solution would be to iterate through the elements of the list, as many other answers noticed.

But if you want to use `map`, you can indeed but you need first to define a function that applies your desired transformation to the second element of each tuple:

```
data = [(1995, 50.28), (1996, 28.52)]

def round_second(tup):
    return tup[0], round(tup[1])

result = list(map(round_second, data))
result
>>> [(1995, 50), (1996, 29)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **lambda** function inside map like this:

```py
result = list(map(lambda x:(x[0], round(x[1])), data))
```

Output is :

```py
[(1995, 50), (1996, 29)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic "for" loop. You can use like that;

```
data = [(1995, 50.28), (1996, 28.52)]

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    data[i] = list(data[i])
    data[i][1] = round(data[i][1])
    data[i]=tuple(data[i])
```

Comment: Would be simpler and more pythonic to just replace the tuple with the new tuple (`data[i] = data[i][0], round(data[i][1])`) instead of converting it to list and back to tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a list comprehension and the built-in *round()* function as follows:

```
data = [(1995, 50.28), (1996, 28.52)]

result = [(x, round(y)) for x, y in data]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[(1995, 50), (1996, 29)]
```

Answer (score -3):

Map is what you need. Use it to apply a function on each tuple. That function would only interact with the second number of each tuple

```
def function(item):
    whatever(item[1])
    return item

data = [(1995, 50.28), (1996, 28.52)]
map(function, data)
```

Comment: You are just replacing the second value with zero. How is this a solution?

Comment: Also, tuples are immutable, so it wouldn't even work

Comment: Replacing the second value isn't important. It was just to show that you can access to it. And indeed, you can't edit tuples anyway.